# Using fetch, why do I need so many "await" statements?

Tags: async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have a fetch instruction in one function that grabs an API key from a server and it's used by a few other objects to deliver that API key to whatever service needs it.

```
export default async function getAPIKey(key) {
    return await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/' + key)).json();
}
```

And in my weather object:

```
export default {
    URI: 'https://api.openweathermap.org',
    getLocalWeather: async function(city=null, countryCode=null) {
        try {
            // fetch the API key from environment
            const API_KEY = await getAPIKey('wx');
            //... rest of code
```

The code as it is works, but I don't understand why I need 3 await statements.  Wouldn't I only need two?  I need one for the `fetch()` in `getAPIKey()`.  Then `.json()` returns a promise because it has to wait for the response body, so I'd need an await where I call the function in `getLocalWeather()`.  But if I don't have two awaits in `getAPIKey()` it just returns `[object Response]`?

Essentially I'm wondering why the following is wrong:

```
export default async function getAPIKey(key) {
    return (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/' + key)).json();
}
```

And in my weather object:

```
export default {
    URI: 'https://api.openweathermap.org',
    getLocalWeather: async function(city=null, countryCode=null) {
        try {
            // fetch the API key from environment
            const API_KEY = await getAPIKey('wx');
            //... rest of code
```

Am I miss-counting? Because I only see two Promises.  I know async/await functions are promises under the hood, so `getAPIKey()` is a promise, but wouldn't that promise be the `.json()` Promise?  And if so why isn't the await where I call the function sufficient?

I'm not sure what what I'm failing to understand.

Comment: As far as I know, whether you return a promise of a value from an `async` function or a value (or even a promise of a promise of a value), `await` should give you the value. I would imagine "why the following is wrong" is not actually wrong; what happens when you run it? Because it can't possibly yield a `Response` object - `Response` is the value of the `fetch` promise; if you run `json` on it, it will either give you a `json` promise, or whatever value the response was JSON-encoding; I can't figure out a scenario where `.json()` would be run and you end up with `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of those `await` statements inside of `getAPIKey()` and your function doesn't even need to be `async`.  You can just do this:

```
export default function getAPIKey(key) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/' + key).json();
}
```

You just want to return the promise from `fetch().json()`.

> The code as it is works, but I don't understand why I need 3 await statements. Wouldn't I only need two?

Actually, you only need one when you do `await getAPIKey()`. The others inside of `getAPIKey()` are not needed at all.

---

When you do something like:

```
export default async function getAPIKey(key) {
    return await fetch('http://localhost:8000/' + key).json();
}
```

You're just adding a superfluous `await` that has no benefit.  The function returns a promise (all `async` functions return a promise) and that promise is resolved when the `await` is done which is exactly the same as just doing `return fetch('http://localhost:8000/' + key).json();` in the first place.  Adding the second `await` also adds no value.